# Revisión de Diseño, código, estructura, patrón en proyecto con mala recepción

Tags: php, revisión-de-código, patrones-de-diseño, arquitectura

Hace algún tiempo vengo desarrollando en una plataforma que si bien es funcional, me dejan comentarios y opiniones negativas sobre la Arquitectura/Estructura/patrón de diseño/anti patrón de diseño, por anticuada, ni siquiera he podido encontrar que patrón es el que utilizaron.

He investigado a profundidad y tanto composer como otros framework utilizan loaders de clases.

#### Estos loaders algunos utilizan `spl_autoload_#######`, en su arquitectura; con la idea de que el desarrollador use namespaces o instancias de clases como:

```php
<?php
class Foo {
    public $aMemberVar = 'aMemberVar Member Variable';
    public $aFuncName = 'aMemberFunc';
   
   
    function aMemberFunc() {
        print 'Inside `aMemberFunc()`';
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
?>
```

para luego:

```php
<?php
$element = 'aMemberVar';
print $foo->$element; // prints "aMemberVar Member Variable"
?>
```

el criterio del Autoload del Composer o framewrok se encarga de realizar el `include_once` o `require_once`, `spl_autoload_#######` del archivo necesario en donde se encuentre la clase o funcion; esto tambien permite ejecutar archivos PHP independientes siempre y cuando tenga los `USE NAMESPACE/NAMESPACE`.

```php
spl_autoload_register(function ($clase) {
    include 'clases/' . $clase . '.clase.php';
});
```

o

```php
namespace Foobar;

class Foo {
    static public function test($nombre) {
        print '[['. $nombre .']]';
    }
}

spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Foo::test'); // A partir de PHP 5.3.0

new ClaseInexistente;
```

Error

> [[Foobar\ClaseInexistente]]
> Fatal error: Class 'Foobar\ClaseInexistente' not found in ...

#### Entonces, en el codigo que estoy trabajando hacen algo completamente Distinto:

El archivo `index.php` que adquiere las costantes del sistema mediante un `requiere_once`, tambien Tienen un clase Padre `CoreApp` que siempre es la que recive todo: acceso inicial, Peticiones: Get, POST, etc

```php
<?php
//require_once 'configs/const/loader.php'; // Acceso a las constantes del sistema
//se agrego las definiciones para hacer que el codigo sea ejecutable.
if (!defined('FILEROOT')) {
    define('FILEROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
}
$paths = [
    'CLASSEXT'  => FILEROOT.'/apps/class/ext/',
    'CLASSMVC'  => FILEROOT.'/apps/class/mvc/',
    'CLASSGEN'  => FILEROOT.'/apps/class/gen/',
    'CLASSCORE' => FILEROOT.'/apps/core/',
    'TPLSTATIC' => FILEROOT.'/html/static/',
    'TPLDASH'   => FILEROOT.'/html/dash/',
    'TPLSITE'   => FILEROOT.'/html/site/',
    'TPLSTATUS' => FILEROOT.'/html/status/',
    'TPLSTORE'  => FILEROOT.'/html/store/'
];
if (!defined('PATHS')) {
    define('PATHS', $paths);
}

class CoreApp
{
    public static $oclass = null;

    // propiedad de la clase en donde se Guardaran las clases que se heredaran en las sub-capas

    public static $ovars = null;

    //  propiedad de la clase en donde se Guardaran las variables que se heredaran en las sub-capas

    private static $instance = null;

    public static function _getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function goCoreApp()
    {
        $this->popClass();
        echo 'hello World';
        //self::$oclass['GEN']['APP']->runInit();
        //self::$oclass['MVC']['CONTROLLER']->runController();
        //self::$oclass['GEN']['APP']->runClose();

    }

    private function popClass()
    {
        //se llama al archivo y la funcion que se encargara de poblar la porpiedad $oclass
        require_once FILEROOT.'/apps/class-manager.php';
        ClassManager::_getInstance()->LoadClass();
    }
}
ob_start();
CoreApp::_getInstance()->goCoreApp();
```

Luego en la siguiente capa llama `ClassManager::_getInstance()->LoadClass();` que es un cargador de clases el cual va a poblar la propiedad `CoreApp::$oclass` que se ejecuta de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
class ClassManager
{
    private static $instance = null;

    public function LoadClass()
    {
        $classPaths = [
            'GEN' => PATHS['CLASSGEN'],
            'MVC' => PATHS['CLASSMVC']
        ];
        $this->requireClassFile(PATHS['CLASSEXT'].'vendor/autoload.php');
        $this->ClassLoader($classPaths);
    }

    public static function _getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function CheckFileIntegrity($file)
    {
        $dl    = ['st' => false, 'msg' => ''];
        $smg1  = '';
        $fileR = file($file);
        $c     = 1;
        foreach ($fileR as $line) {
            if (!strlen(trim($line))) {
                $smg1 .= 'Incorrect space/Linebreak found file: '.$file.EOL_SYS.'Line: '.$c.EOL_SYS;
                $dl['st'] = true;
                ++$c;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        $dl['msg'] = $smg1;
        return $dl;
    }

    private function ClassLoader($classPaths)
    {
        foreach ($classPaths as $key => $path) {
            $dl          = [];
            $class_store = &CoreApp::$oclass[$key];
            $files       = array_diff(
                scandir($path, 1),
                ['..', '.']
            );
            foreach ($files as $key => $name) {
                if (strpos($name, 'class-') !== false) {
                    $fl_dir = $path.$name;
                    $dl     = $this->CheckFileIntegrity($fl_dir);
                    if (!$dl['st']) {
                        $this->requireClassFile($fl_dir);
                        $name = explode("-", preg_replace('#\.php#', '', $name));
                        foreach ($name as $key => $cl_name) {
                            $name[$key] = ucfirst(strtolower($cl_name));
                        }
                        $new_name_class = implode('', $name);
                        $instance_class = strtoupper(
                            preg_replace('#\Class#', '', $new_name_class)
                        );
                        $new_name_class .= 'Manager';
                        $class_store[$instance_class] = $new_name_class::_getInstance();
                    } else {
                        echo
                            'PHP files cannot have line breaks at the beginning '.
                            'or end.<br> There is a problem with this file: <b> '.
                            PATHS['CLASSGEN'].$name.'</b> <br> <br>'.
                            $dl['msg'];
                        die;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function requireClassFile($file)
    {
        return require_once $file;
    }
}
```

**Dependencia:**
Para que este Script sea funciona se requiere crear en el root una carpeta con la siguiente estructura:

`/apps/class/ext/` #donde se colocara toda la instalación de composer y librerías externas accesibles por autoload de composer.

`/apps/class/gen/` #donde se colocara toda las clases genéricas.

`/apps/class/mvc/` #donde se colocara toda las clases mvc.

**Ejemplo de una Clase Genérica y una MVC:**

> class-test.php //nombre de la clase debe iniciar con `class-`

```php
class ClassTestManager
{
    private static $instance = null;
    
    public static function _getInstance()
    {
    
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    public function test()
    {
        echo 'hello world';
    }
}
```

**En resumen:**

para el final tienen la propiedad `CoreApp::$oclass` con todas las clases pre-instaciadas.
una vez esto realizado desde cualquier capa se puede llamar a una funcion de la siguiente forma:

```php
self::$oclass['GEN']['TEST']->test();

self::$oclass['GEN']['APP']->runInit();
self::$oclass['MVC']['CONTROLLER']->runController();
self::$oclass['GEN']['APP']->runClose();
```

o

```php
CoreApp::$oclass['GEN']['VARS']->expVariable(true, true, false, true, CoreApp::$ovars, [$stuser, $isdata, $isdatatype, $iscron, $iswser])
```

no requiere del uso de `USE NAMESPACE/NAMESPACE` o de uso de `Instancias`; tampoco de `extender`.

**Pero nunca he tenido una respuesta canónica sobre el por qué? 

[Link del Proyecto en Github](https://github.com/arcanisgk/Last-Hammer) 

este es un proyecto con poca documentación en el código, Preguntas:**

1. Que patrón es ?
2. Cuales son las debilidades de esta Arquitectura/Estructura/patrón de diseño/anti patrón de diseño o la logical del uso de un Objeto o propiedad para heredar Clases y Funciones pre-inicializadas?
3. Que Errores puedo estar cometiendo, que deje de funcionar la aplicación o ser un exploit?
4. Que mejoras (re-factory) puede tener el código de la clase `class ClassManager` para hacerla más eficiente?

**Update Comentarios / Aclaraciones**

1. Me indican que una debilidad pre-inicializar clases que no se usan por que leen en disco y guardan datos en en la memoria ram y pueden impactar en la velocidad del sistema, ejemplo saber la hora del servidor para cualquier uso dentro del sistema.

**Resp:** Lo cierto es que solo se lee en disco una vez, y se guarda tambien una vez en ram, y el recurso queda guardado en el objeto/Propiedad `CoreApp::$oclass` el cual proporciona acceso en RAM en tiempo de ejecucion a cualquier Clase/funcion sin necesidad de recurrir a `SPL_AUTOLo-`... Es o no es una Debilidad; necesitara probar la escalabilidad cierto.

Comment: Y ahora que esta aca, las unicas preguntas respondibles son la 2 (si es que existe) y la 3 (si es que existe).. la 4, en el proyecto.. la 1 es basada en opiniones..

Comment: @gbianchi gracias ya corregí las preguntas, comenzó la lluvia de votos negativos.

Comment: @Marcos he visto algo parecido en fabrica y singleton, pero no me convence donde la ubicaría; en realidad no se inilizan las clases simplemente se instancia el acceso.

Comment: @Marcos puedes dar una explicación mas profunda de como esto seria una debilidad o en que momento del código se convierte en una debilidad y si tienes un ejemplo de como se mejoraría este punto sin necesidad de recurrir a librerías de terceros o modificar el uso de `CoreApp::$oclass`?.

Comment: @Marcos tu punto es que crees que eso se ejecuta cada vez que necesito leer la hora. lo cual seria cierto si usara SPL_aut..... y necesitara en diferentes capas saver la hora del servidor llamando a una funcion especifica para formatearla por ejemplo...

Comment: @Marcos en realidad se instancia una sola vez y se guarda el recurso en el objeto/propiedad `CoreApp::$oclass`; si se lee del disco y se guarda en ram pero una sola vez,  desde ese punto puedes acceder a la hora del servidor en cualquier capa de la programación y se usa mucho, saber la hora del servidor por temas de logs y registros que te parece???

Comment: @Marcos Esto se aplica únicamente para clases Genéricas y que tienen que ver con MVC o clases externas.

Comment: Existe un apartado de clases de la Lógica (Formularios, eventos, procesos que si se instancias a necesidad en tiempo de ejecución)...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112216/discussion-between-francisco-nunez-and-marcos).

Comment: si al final de cada evento cliente servidor la memoria se limpia. no deja nada...y en burdas pruebas que he realizado en otro version del sistema el consumo de memoria esta en 20 mb con un usuario y con 50 usuarios esta en 22mb cuando se ejecuta una simplefuncion sin manipulacion de dato hay un pico de uso de memoria de 23 megas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Que patrón es?

**Resp.:** no es un patrón definido; lo que se implementa es un patrón "ortodoxo" de la época en que aun no existían los namespace y es una mezcla entre fabrica, construcción y Singleton. no esta mal planteado, es manejable pero no la mejor opción, entre las existentes (canónicamente no tiene ni siquiera Registro este patrón).

2. Cuales son las debilidades de esta Arquitectura/Estructura/patrón de diseño/anti patrón de diseño o la logical del uso de un Objeto o propiedad para heredar Clases y Funciones pre-inicializadas?

**Resp.:** la única Debilidad Apreciable es; su limitaciones principalmente con la trazabilidad por software del código ya que los Métodos Simbólicos tienen estos problemas y se debe recuriri una indexaciones por busqueda de texto, esto esta presente únicamente en ST3; pero VScode y phpStorm no tienen el soporte adecuado/nativo.

**Ejemplo:**

```
self::$oclass['MVC']['CONTROLLER']->runController();
```

> Los editores actuales no tiene la capacidad de trazar la ruta de acceso a la funcion `runController` debido a que esta anidando simbólicamente en un `Array` que no fue declarado; si no que fue construido en tiempo real.

3. Que Errores puedo estar cometiendo, que deje de funcionar la aplicación o ser un exploit?

**Resp.:** Como dije en un principio el único exploit que puede tener depende de la version de php y los errores cometidos por el programador... no existen Exploit si se presenta correctamente una capa de seguridad.

4. Que mejoras (re-factory) puede tener el código de la clase `class ClassManager` para hacerla más eficiente?

**Resp.:** normalmente Todos los proyectos con estas características suelen migran a patrones de diseño que empleen el uso de namespace y control de recursos basados en una lógica establecida en común entre los desarrolladores ya que no responde a ninguna estructura de framework de desarrollo.

Actualmente el Desarrollo esta siendo refactorizado y migrado a este ultimo punto mencionado.